# Subdomain htaccess Rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have dashboard.domain.com that acts as a dashboard for clients.
In the .htaccess file for the subdomain I have..

```
RewriteRule ^v/([a-zA-Z])/ index.php?flag=$1 [L]
```

In the dashboard navigation I have two links: "/v/t" and "/logout"

As the rewrite rule stands, it works for the /v/ links, but when I go to the logout link, it throws up a 404 error. What am I missing in my rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing in my rewrite?

Emm, **^v/** in yours regexp and lack of it in the "/logout" link?

Comment: Well, I want certain pages to be dashboard.domain.com/v/<flag> and still have normal pages like dashboard.domain.com/logout , dashboard.domain.com/login , dashboard.domain.com/<whatever> .. so the lack of it is intentional as far as the URL to use, but don't know why the /v/ rewrite is affecting the logout/login/other normal addresses that point to actual pages without rewrites.